# Where can I find a complete list of Magento events?

Tags: event-observer, magento-1

I know that Magento has a hook-like system called events. Does anyone have a complete list or a script which can be used to determine which events can be called?

Comment: I use this as a nice cheat sheet http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Comment: @DerrikNyomo - you should post that as an answer along with a summary of the information which it provides. :-)

Comment: Cheat sheets for events are in fact more of a hassle, as they give you a false sense that 'the event I want does not exist' and you may waste hours of coding, having missed an event that could have been used (since a lot are dynamically created)

I posted an answer to this question : [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176/whats-the-last-event-dispatched-before-content-is-sent-to-the-browser) and my answer also pertains to this question. It dos not give you a complete 'list', but it does give you a complete list of events for the action/page load you are interested in hooking to.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There is not a list of all magento events, because most of the events are dynamically named.

If you ask me, knowing these key events (and the consequences) is a good starting point (beside the list from nick):

Every Object extended from Mage_Core_Model_Abstract dispatches a lot events around loading, saving and deleting:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:255
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_before', $params);
// e.g. sales_order_load_before, checkout_cart_load_before
```

For example to add checks, after the object was loaded

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:267
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_after', $this->_getEventData());
// e.g. cms_page_load_after
```

to add additional data to the object before it is saved

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:391
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
// e.g. catalog_product_save_before
```

To save other models after the "parent" was saved

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:466  
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
// e.g. catalogrule_rule_save_after
```

clean up, before the model is deleted

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:501
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_before', $this->_getEventData());
// e.g. store_delete_before
```

clean up, before the model is deleted - or maybe afterwards? You are here still in the transaction!

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:529
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_after', $this->_getEventData());
// e.g. website_delete_after
```

If you want to be sure the entity was deleted

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:541
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_commit_after', $this->_getEventData());
// e.g. customer_delete_commit_after
```

The collections extended from Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract have a two generic events too:

For example: to change the SQL to load the collection:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php:588
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_before', array(
    $this->_eventObject => $this
));
// e.g. sales_order_status_history_collection_load_before
```

For example: to add additional data to the objects:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php:637
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_after', array(
    $this->_eventObject => $this
));
// e.g. sales_order_shipment_collection_load_after
```

Comment: Very much a good answer; hoping for something we can tuck in the wiki. The importance of the `_eventPrefix` for the model events, the targeted request events, the occasionally-useful generic block events, and the importance of logging to find events

Comment: Excellent. I wanted to note that in Magento 2 they really need to ensure all the core classes have a defined event prefix. I have actually rewritten classes just to define the event prefix so I can cleanly hook into save/load events. Hmm. Actually I think I'll go check the Magento 2 source myself.

Comment: The approach I usually take is, a quick edit/save/revert to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` and `mage::log($eventName,null,'events.txt',true);` to the `dispatchEvent` method. Load the page I'm trying to observe. Obviously don't leave this as is and revert once your var/logs/events.txt is created. Dirty, yes. Quick, yes. :)

Comment: good, if you want your observer to be on one page. But be carful, there are events which should be dispatched, but might be not. There is a order or payment event which is not thrown, when payed with paypal...

Comment: Is there any event gets fired after shipment creation in magento @FabianBlechschmidt

Comment: of course shipment_save_before/after (or something alike)

Answer (score 48):

Do the bloody `grep 'Mage::dispatchEvent' app/ -rsn` This will provide you with a list of events specific to your installation as the list of events may vary depending on Magento version, customizations and extensions installed.

Comment: That is best advice, it will include 3rd party modules events as well. Usually when I want to know which events I can hook to for particular page, I log app:dispatchEvent parameters.

Comment: The grep will also give you bad information: For example, it claims that `sales_order_place_after` will happen, but it seems that the call to fire it is commented out of `Checkout/Type/Onepage.php`.

Comment: This is a poor answer as it will only pick up a fraction of the available events as it completely misses all the dynamically generated events. @PetarDzhambazov gives good advice to log from the dispatcher and then load pages you are interested in. Best answer by far is the accepted answer given by FabianBlechschmidt

Answer (score 26):

I use this as a nice cheat sheet http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/. It has all the events that that can be called in 1.7.

Comment: Since you've already done a good job of linking the content, best to also provide the content here in case Nick says "screw Magento" and deletes his page :-)

Comment: I'm not a fan of this list, because 1: it's incomplete, 2: there are other 1231 blogs about Magento with "all" the events in Magento (+some wiki pages on Magento).

Comment: @benmarks guess what happened in the mean time...

Answer (score 9):

I know that this question has been answered I just add my way here:

- I prepare page that I want to observe in my browser
- I open app/Mage.php
- for `public static function dispatchEvent` (ln:~446) in the begining I add
  `//Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);`
- uncomment that line,
- refresh page that I'm on
- comment again that line

Then you open var/log/events.log (~40kb) and see a whole lot events on that page only! :)

Comment: This will miss some events which are fired before store config is merged.

Answer (score 6):

Answer has already been accepted but Ill post my answer anyway for the future:

If you want to see the list of events that Magento has you have 3 options:

**1)** Google for it, there are a lot of people who have compiled a list of Magento events

**2)** Create a module that hooks on the `controller_action_predispatch` event which is the event that is called before any other event is called. Inside this module you can log some events that are dispatched:

Add the following on config.xml

```
<events>
    <controller_action_postdispatch>
        <observers>
            <controller_action_after>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>hookToControllerActionPostDispatch</method>
            </controller_action_after>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_postdispatch>
</events>
```

And inside the yourmodule/Model/Observer:

```
public function hookToControllerActionPostDispatch($observer) {
    Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());
}
```

The above would log every event that is dispatched...

**3)** If you have SSH access you can run the following command to get an overview of all the events (and their files where they are dispatched):

```
cd /path/to/<magento-root>
grep -nris 'dispatchEvent' app/code/
```

Comment: Sorry - while #3 is good, the information in 1 & 2 from your answer is really not correct. 1) There are a few events fired before `controller_action_predispatch`, notably `controller_front_init_before`. 2) This approach simply *will not* log every event that is dispatched, is this a typo or incomplete section?

Comment: Edited it to "most" ;)

Comment: Sorry, still not very accurate :-( - there are so many more events dispatched (predispatch, layout, rendering, as well as model and collection loads)...

Comment: Updated the answer to "some events".

Answer (score 4):

I am using Magento Developer Toolbar that has nice feature of displaying events that can be observed on loaded page.

Answer (score 4):

I have done a grep on core Mage module of Magento , and complied a list,

[Exhaustive List of Magento Events](http://huztechbuzz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/complete-list-of-all-events-in-magento/)

P.S. As pointed out, may contain events which are inside deprecated functions of Magento, so do check the file and line reference before implementation.

Open for suggestions!

Comment: You're still missing all of the subclassed magic events. Can't be grepped for.

Comment: Magic events as in? The ones which are dynamic? Could you elaborate plz @benmarks

Comment: For example https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php#L255

Comment: @benmarks i agree, i do not think we need to prepare a list explicitly for this

Comment: Hence my comment, which was offered based on the use of "exhaustive"

Answer (score 4):

```
grep "::dispatchEvent" -R * | sort -u

grep "eventPrefix" -R * | sort -u
```

The previous listed grep command would render duplicates (a lot) and it doesn't cover the list of event prefixes that would be required to understand the dynamically generated event names. These commands render both lists with only unique values. You could add the -n flag like the other grep answer and get the line number i suppose. But the question didn't ask where in the code they all were. ~_~

Comment: we have similar answer here. Refer [@TimBezhashvyly](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162/3535)'s answer

Comment: sort of.... the previous listed grep command would render duplicates (a lot) and it doesn't cover the list of event prefixes that would be required to understand the dynamically generated event names. These commands render both lists with only unique values. You could add the -n flag like the other grep answer and get the line number i suppose. But the question didn't ask where in the code they all were.

Comment: could you please add this description to your answer. Then your answer become super cool... (am ready to do an upvote then ) :-)

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Yes. +1 for that. :)

Answer (score 3):

theres a cheat sheet here also http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/magento-event-observer-list/

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events

Here you can find complete list of observer events.

Comment: No, you cannot. There is no such thing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here you can view the most of existing events:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events

Answer (score 3):

Refer these cheat sheets

https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/
http://rabee.me/codes/magento/cheatsheet/1.9/

It will helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all list of backend + frontend events on single link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events

Comment: This is not a complete resource, because there is no complete resource.

Comment: Duplicate answer... Move your eyes 200px up ;)

Answer (score 2):

If someone ever needs an updated list, I'm trying to keep this one up to date:

https://gist.github.com/digitalpianism/d8157c6b492238af2ed7809e5e3a134e

Answer (score 1):

You can find all magento-1x events by following url. [**https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Events+Reference**](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Events+Reference)