# What's the last event dispatched before content is sent to the browser?

Tags: cookie, event-observer

I need to set or update a cookie, but I want to ensure that all (or as much as possible) of the request processing occurs before my cookie generation code runs.  i.e. if the user logs in, I want to ensure that the login processing has occurred before my code runs, or if the user adds something to their cart I want to know that all cart processing is done first.

Are there any events that are dispatched immediately before a response is sent to the browser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last event dispatched in Magento 1.x before content is rendered is

```
controller_front_send_response_after
```

If there are no extra requirements in observer data that you would need, this one should be perfect for you.

Comment: Actually, "controller_front_send_response_before" looks like what I need.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 8):

A handy trick, to find events fired during a page request / action, is to temporarily edit app/Mage.php and write out the events fired to var/log/system.log

```
 public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

to

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
    {
        if(mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
           mage::log($name);
        }
        Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
        return $result;
    }
```

and then tail the log file. I have found this method extremely useful, and saved a lot of time hunting for that elusive event to use.

Naturally you should remove it immediately, as you do not want to commit changed core files. I wrap it into the developer check, just in case.

Comment: You can also enable the Profiler, it gives you extensive information of what happens in a page load. All events triggered are echoed there as well.