# How to trace events / Alternatives of Mage::dispatchEvent to hook events?

Tags: event-observer

Testing out observers and following tutos , i have created an observer for 'catalog_product_save_after' that worked.
But searching through the files i cannot find the Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_after');

How is this possible?

This question is interesting for me because at first the observer i have setted was not working and i thought it was because the event were simply not existing.

Comment: It has to be somewhere, but the declaration doesn't always go the way you pointed out, it's sometimes like $this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after' you see?

Comment: not easy to verify if an event is indeed existing in our version

Comment: Indeed. But are you sure that it wasn't fired because of Magento? or is it because your product didn't meet the requirements for it to be fired?

Comment: it was initially not fired because of errors in my config.xml

Comment: I see, is it ok now?

Comment: i will edit my question

Comment: sorry I am still a bit confused about this question are you asking where `catalog_product_save_after` is dispatched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i strongly recommend to set this observer as a tool to trace possible hooks when working in creating new observer for any specific event

[How to Know The Magento Event that We Want to Hook](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314/how-to-know-the-magento-event-that-we-want-to-hook)

thus i have created in the module Logevent the config.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<modules>
    <Maticode_Logevent>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </Maticode_Logevent>
</modules>


<global>
    <models>
        <Logevent>
            <class>Maticode_Logevent_Model</class>
        </Logevent>
    </models>

    <events>


        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <Logevent>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Logevent/observer</class>
                    <method>controller_action_predispatch</method>
                </Logevent>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>

    </events>
</global>
```

and the Model/observer.php

```
            <?php

 class Maticode_Logevent_Model_Observer {
public function controller_action_predispatch($observer) {
    Mage::log ( $observer->getEvent ()->getControllerAction ()->getFullActionName (),null, 'eventlog.log' );
}
  }
```

This way , in the

```
        var/log/eventlog.log file
```

i can visualize a possible hook on any tested actions

Comment: here's a cheat sheet of most of Magento's events in 1.7 http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/