# Observer's getCollection() not being rewritten

Tags: overrides, event-observer

Is this standard behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

```
// in event 'catalog_product_collection_load_before'
get_class($observer->getCollection());
 > Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
get_class(Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_collection'));
 > MyStuff_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
```

I'm trying to avoid rewriting the block that outputs this code, since one of our plugins already does so (bleh), so that's why I'm using the event.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what your question really is. What do you want to do, what did you try so far and what's your problem with your approach?

Comment: I've overridden the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` class with my own, but found that in an observer which sends `catalog/resource_product_collection`, the original class is sent, as opposed to my rewritten one. From the reading I've done since then, it looks like instance is being created with `new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` (or something similar) which blocks the rewrite.

Comment: Did one of these answers help you? If so, please mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the option to include the entire `Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php` with my new methods in the `app/code/local/Mage` folder, but I'm hesitant to resort to that unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the parent collection within your own block?

```
class Company_Module_Block_Customcollection extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {

    /**
     * Set collection to Product list before Html is rendered
     */
    public function _beforeToHtml() {
        parent::setCollection(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setCollection()); // <- Or custom collection
        parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

You can observe `controller_action_layout_load_before` and use something like

```
public function observe($observer) {
    if ($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index')) {
         $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('module_block');
    }
}
```

- [Where can I find a complete list of Magento events?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like someone made it wrong and instanciated with `new` instead of the factory methods `getSingleton()` and `getModel()` there is no way to fix this in your module.

So if you want to have the correct class, you have to change the module which uses the `new`

Comment: Which solution would you say is more correct, fix the code that did not use factory methods by replacing it in the `app/code/local/Mage` folder, then override the `collection` the normal way, **or** just override the `collection` in `app/code/local/Mage`?

Comment: I'm sure that the code which makes the problems is not in `code/Mage`. So I would fix the community module :)