# sales_order_payment_transaction_save_commit_after Event

Tags: event-observer, ee-1.11, sagepay

We have an observer listening to the sales_order_payment_transaction_save_commit_after event. However, the event doesn't always fire on checkout when using Sage Pay Pro (it works fine for PayPal and other methods and sometimes works for Sage Pay). Is there anything which can stop this event firing? This is EE  1.11.0.

Sorry for quite vague information, if you need anything else then let me know.

Comment: Not sure the cause but I do recall another similar comment on the issue: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events?rq=1#comment4012_167

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems to fire some times but not others. I can only think that there is an exception being thrown during checkout but I can't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with Ebizmarts who were very helpful, it was simply a case that the module didn't fire this event. Instead, we used sales_order_place_after which called late enough for us to use how we wished.