# (display me) all the event names which are fired by the magento when any event or events occurs

Tags: magento-1.8

In Magento, how can I see all the event names which are fired when an event occurs in the frontend or backend (after some customer or admin action)?

Comment: check this thread
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean method to do this (in my knowledge). However you can log all of of event names that get called during a page request. For this put this single code snippet inside `Mage::dispatchEvent()`.

File : `app\Mage.php`

```
 self::log('Event : ' . $name, null, 'events.log', true);
```

Put this code inside the function `dispatchEvent()` as its first line. Then load any page. Now go to the location `var\log\events.log` and open it. You can see an enormous records that holds event names in it.

You can see multiple records for the same event name. That is because, those events get called multiple times

**Note:** Do not forget to revert back the changes in `Mage.php`, after inspection. Also always delete the previous contents inside `events.log`, before the another page load takes place.

Hope that helps