# My cron job and cron.php fails?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

Hope some of your clever magento guys can help me :)

I have a custom plugin with a mobil case designer - when an order is placed and the payment are registered, cron should automaticly send this designed case to a printmanager.

In my cpanel i have a cron job that activates cron.php - but nothing happens to the order, it will not send it throug. But it will send it through if I manually activate cron.php in my browser?? Why and what can I do? I have been in touch with my hosting, and the log says it activates the cron.php like it should

Comment: Firstly, you should be executing `cron.sh`, not `cron.php` - so that you don't double -execute your cron. Secondly, for visibility of crons, consider using Aoe_Scheduler, its very handy.

Comment: Hey - thx for your comment :) So my cron job should activate .sh instead of php? I too a look at the Aoe_scheduler - will try to test it on demo site since it is only supporting up to 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **cron job** is a scheduled task that is executed by the system at a specified time/date interval.

Since orders are placed at a more random interval and the only way to catch all order would be to run it every second  or do a look up for all orders place since last cron ran, therefore using a cron is not the best solution and would require a lot of work to catch and process all orders.

A better way to accomplish what you are trying to do in magento is to use event/observer

You could create an observer for `sales_order_place_after` see [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) (if you are not processing credit card in realtime then you could use another event see [Where can I find a complete list of Magento events?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events)

Comment: Hello - thx for your answer. I will take a look in to your suggestion.