# How to get Magento 1.9 CE's events list and which event is called when?

Tags: event-observer, ce-1.9.2.2

Need a list of Magento 1.9.2.2 latest events, along with specification of which event is called when.

For example "sales_order_payment_place_end".

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events

Answer (score 7):

You can find a list on https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/ although it's probably not `1.9.2.2`.

Alternatively you can do a grep on the `./app/code/` directory to generate your own list.

`grep -Rsn 'Mage::dispatchEvent' . > events.txt`

Comment: @VickyDev you're welcome! don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: This helped. But still can't grep all events out as mentioned here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events?answertab=votes#tab-top